# how to save the selected dropdown option along with other input fields

Tags: apex, visualforce

in the below code i am able to save all the fields to record except the selected option from the dropdown

```html
<apex:page controller="lndController" docType="html-5.0" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Request Components">
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Embed Club</title>
        <style>
        
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
             
        
            <label>Member ID:</label>
            <apex:inputField value="{!lend.Member__c}"/> <!-- inputText changed to inputField, either u have to query and get the member sfid once user type the member id -->
            <label>Component:</label>
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedRecordId}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Records}"/>   
    </apex:selectList>
            
                <label>Expected Return Date:</label>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Lend.Expected_Return_Date__c}"/> <!-- no need to type="date" it will automatically take the field type-->
            <div id="lower">               
                <apex:commandbutton value="Submit" action="{!submit}"/>
            </div><!--/ lower-->
            </apex:pageBlockSection>     
            
        </body>
    
    
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

```java
public class lndController {
    public Lend_Component__c Lend{get; set;}
    public Components__c Comp{get; set;}
    public String userid{get;set;}
    public String selectedRecordId {get; set;}
    //public String records {get;set;}
  
    public List<SelectOption> getRecords() {
        
        List<SelectOption> lstOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<Components__c> lstComponent = [select Component_ID__c,Component_Name__c from Components__c Limit 20];
       
        for(Components__c Comp : lstComponent){
            lstOptions.add(new SelectOption(Comp.Component_ID__c, Comp.Component_Name__c));
        }
       
        return lstOptions;
        
    }
     public lndController() {
            Lend = new Lend_Component__c();
         Lend.Component__c = SelectedRecordId;
            
        }
    public PageReference submit(){ 
         insert Lend;
        
        
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/choicePage');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any settings for `Lend.Component__c` on the form, so when the `select` is changed, its value won't be updated.

To fix this, except 2 @Callum solutions, you can try like this:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!Lend.Component__c}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Records}"/>   
</apex:selectList>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is related to the setting of the Component__c field on the Lend_Component__c record when a new value is selected from the picklist.

When you select a new value, it's simply being assigned to the selectedRecordId attribute, but that is not then assigned to the record itself.

To fix this, you can do one of two things:

1. Add a setter method to the selectedRecordId. This will assign the selected Id to the lookup on the Lend record as it is selected. This is the approach I would recommend.

   ```
   public Contact Lend{get; set;}
   public Account Comp{get; set;}
   public String userid{get;set;}
   public String selectedRecordId {set;}
   public void setSelectedRecordId(String recordId){
       Lend.Component__c= recordId;
   }
   ```
2. Explictly assign the selectedRecordId to the Lend record during your submit method.

```
    public PageReference submit(){ 
        
        Lend.Component__c = selectedRecordId;
        insert Lend;
        
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/choicePage');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
        
    }
```